# Lucene :- How to check whether the given date is between two indexed date fields or Not?

Tags: lucene

We are using lucene 2.4.0.

Some Thousand Docs are indexed in file system

Below Two Fields index along with many other fields:

I am using MultiFieldQueryParser because many other fields are involved in search query.

```
    EffectiveDate="1970-01-01T00:00:00-05:00"
    ExpirationDate="2035-12-31T00:00:00-05:00"
```

**1.)**

Is there any way to check whether the given date is between two indexed date fields or Not

**2.)**

Is there any way to set max size to the return results in lucene .

Comment: About 'countValue': I have no idea what you are referring to.

Comment: @femtoRgon countValue = its nothing but a value. can we set max size to the return results in lucene .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your dates are well formatted for lexicographic ordering, so to check whether a value is between two different fields will follow a pattern like.  Lucene didn't begin supporting [open-ended queries in the StandardQueryParser](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-995) until version 3.6, so selecting adequantely large upper and lower bounds, to emulate an open ended query:

```
+EffectiveDate:[0000-01-01 TO value] +ExpirationDate:[value TO 9999-12-31]
```

Which, I believe, won't work well with `MultiFieldQueryParser`.  You may need to run the rest of your Query through that parser, and something like the above through a `StandardQueryParser` and merge them with a [`BooleanQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html).

you could also construct the same query manually, something like:

```
TermRangeQuery tqlow = new TermRangeQuery("EffectiveDate", null, new BYtesRef(value), true, true);
TermRangeQuery tqlow = new TermRangeQuery("ExpirationDate", new BYtesRef(value), null, true, true);
BooleanQuery betweenQuery = new BooleanQuery();
betweenQuery.add(new BooleanClause(tqlow, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
betweenQuery.add(new BooleanClause(tqhigh, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));

Query parsedQuery = MultiFieldQueryParser.parse............

BooleanQuery rootQuery = new BooleanQuery();
rootQuery.add(new BooleanClause(parsedQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
rootQuery.add(new BooleanClause(betweenQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
```

Comment: countValue = its nothing but a value. can we set max size to the return results in lucene .

Comment: Still not sure what you mean.  You can set the max number of results found with your [IndexSearcher.search](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#search(org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int)) call, and you can get the number of  hits found from [TopDocs.totalHits](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TopDocs.html#totalHits).  Either of those what you are trying to get?

Comment: eg:) if I setted maxCount = 15  then it should return top 15 results.. Is that possible

Comment: Like I said, pass it to your call to IndexSearcher.search.  Unless you pass it a Collector instead, you are actually required to give it a maximum number of documents to return.

Comment: +ExpirationDate:[value TO *] some problem with this range query

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337098/lucene-2-4-0-range-query-is-not-working-as-expected

Comment: To accept answer :- edit you answer to +ExpirationDate:[value TO null] it will help others too