# Lucene 2.4.0 Range Query is not working as expected

Tags: full-text-search, lucene, range-query

Below are the indexed fields with value:

```
 EffectiveDate="1970"
 ExpirationDate="2035"
```

Code to create index and seach:

```
public class IndexTest{

static Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
static IndexSearcher isearcher;

@BeforeClass
public static void createIndex() throws CorruptIndexException, LockObtainFailedException, IOException{
    Store s = Field.Store.YES;
    Store ds = Field.Store.YES;
    Index IA = Field.Index.ANALYZED;
    Index INA = Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED;

    IndexWriter iwriter = new IndexWriter("C://tmp/testindex/sample", analyzer, true);
    iwriter.setMaxFieldLength(25000);

    //Sample dummy docs
    Document doc = new Document();
    Document doc1 = new Document();
    Document doc2 = new Document();
    Document doc3 = new Document();

    doc.add(new Field("EffectiveDate", "1970", ds, IA));
    doc.add(new Field("ExpirationDate", "2035", ds, IA));

    iwriter.addDocument(doc);

    doc1.add(new Field("EffectiveDate", "1970", ds, IA));
    doc1.add(new Field("ExpirationDate", "2035", ds, IA));

    iwriter.addDocument(doc1);

    iwriter.optimize();
    iwriter.close();
}

   @Test
public void testRangeQuery() throws java.text.ParseException, Exception, IOException{


    isearcher = new IndexSearcher("E://tmp/testindex/sample");

       // String rQuery = " EffectiveDate : [* TO 1971 ]"; 
           // String rQuery = " EffectiveDate : [1960 TO 2000]"; 
           // String rQuery = " ExpirationDate : [2000 TO 2050]"; 


           //Below Query is Not Working
           String rQuery = " ExpirationDate : [2000 TO *]"; 

    MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(
              new String[] { 
                 "EffectiveDate"
                 ,"ExpirationDate"}, analyzer);
        //parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.OR);
        parser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
        Query query = parser.parse(rQuery);
        System.out.println("Str = "+rQuery);
        System.out.println("query = "+query);
        Hits hits = isearcher.search(query);
        assertEquals(2, hits.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < hits.length(); i++) {
            Document hitDoc = hits.doc(i);
            System.out.println("hitDoc = "+hitDoc);
            System.out.println(hitDoc.get("Code"));
        }
     System.out.println("1query = "+query);

}
```

Logic :- current date should be between these two field.

Below Range query is working:-

```
EffectiveDate : [ * TO 2013-06-26 ]
```

**Below Range query is not working:-**

```
ExpirationDate : [2013-06-26 TO *]
```

**Any help would be highly appreciable.Thanks in advance**

Comment: Can you show how you index those two fields?  Also, what do you mean by not working? (Too many hits?  Missing hits?  None?  Throws an exception?)

Comment: No doc found... But all the doc values are with in the range

Comment: So, are you able to provide the code where those fields are added to the document when indexing?

Comment: updated the question with code

Comment: Ahh!  Apologies, wasn't paying attention to your Lucene version, earlier.  Support for open-ended ranges wasn't added to QueryParser until version 3.6!  See my answer for some explanation as to why your answer works, and what to be cautious of with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Lucene query parser didn't accept open ended ranges (like `ExpirationDate : [2013-06-26 TO *]`) until Version 3.6 (see [the related ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-995)).

Your answer, of using `ExpirationDate : [2013-06-26 TO null]` might mislead you down the road.  `null` is not treated as a special value, but rather just a word!  Lexicographically, punctuation (`*`) is before numerals `2013`, and numerals are before letters (`null`) (Described very generically, Ordering is based on [Unicode value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters), I believe).

So, while `ExpirationDate : [2013-06-26 TO null]` and `EffectiveDate : [ * TO 2013-06-26 ]` do work,

neither `ExpirationDate : [2013-06-26 TO *]` nor `EffectiveDate : [null TO 2013-06-26 ]` will.

In version 2.4.0, what you'll need to do to provide for your search, is to come up with adequately high and low values to consider the search effectively open-ended, for all intents and purposes, such as:

```
+EffectiveDate : [0000-01-01 TO 2013-06-26 ] +ExpirationDate : [2013-06-26 TO 9999-12-31]
```

Using something like:

```
+ExpirationDate : [2013-06-26 TO null] +EffectiveDate : [ * TO 2013-06-26 ]
```

May work, but for all the wrong reasons.